# Generate a random sequence of bits. What is the expected length of the second subsequence of consecutive same bits?

Tags: probability

**Question.** Generate a sequence of bits, each bit having a chance $p$ of being $1$ and a chance $1-p$ of being $0$. Collect subsequences of consecutive same bits, starting from the first bit. What is the expected length of the second such collection?

For example, the sequence $\{1,1,0,1,0,0,1,\ldots\}$ has collections

$$\{1,1\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0,0\},\{1,\ldots\},\ldots$$

and the length of the second collection is $1$.

**My Solution.** Let $X$ denote the first bit of the first collection and $Y$ denote the length of the second collection. So

$$E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E(Y|X=1)p+E(Y|X=0)(1-p)$$

since $E(Y|X=1)$ is geometric (counting the number of $0$s until a $1$), I would suspect that the count is $1/p-1$, noting that $1/p$ counts all the $0$s *and* the terminating $1$, the latter of which I don't want. The other case is symmetric, so I can write

$$\begin{split}E(Y) & =\left(\frac1p-1\right)p+\left(\frac1{1-p}-1\right)(1-p) \\ & =1-p+1-1+p \\ & =1\end{split}$$

So I thought I'd leave it at that.

**The Problem.** The solution sheet says the answer is $2$, and someone else in class believes it is $3$. My mistake is not clear to me after some hours of deliberation, and I would not know whether the solution sheet or my classmate is correct. So, if I made a mistake, where is it?

Comment: For the expectation of the geometric I had interchanged $p$ and $1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: Thanks to OP for correcting a serious error I made.

The probability the first collection starts with $1$ is $p$, and therefore the probability the second collection starts with $0$ is $p$, and the probability it starts with $1$ is $1-p$.

**Given** the first bit in the second collection is $0$, the expected number of **additional** $0$'s in the collection is $\frac{1}{p}-1$, for a total of $\frac{1}{p}$.  A similar analysis works for first bit in the collection a $1$ bit.

So the expectation is $p\cdot\frac{1}{p}+(1-p)\cdot\frac{1}{1-p}$.

Comment: Okay, I don't think this is right. The first collection is expected to have length $p/(1-p)+(1-p)/p$ (verified by solutions manual and my own derivation). The second collection conditioned on the first bit in the first collection (the conditioning tells me what the second collection is composed of) should behave like a geometric distribution, except that the conditioning doesn't give me an extra bit because that condition belongs to the first collection.

Comment: That condition belongs to every collection.

Comment: Aha, I understand. The condition determines what I pick on my $i$th collection, so it gives me a count of $1$ everywhere. OK, the solution makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. And thanks for correcting my bad error about $1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about every collection except the second.  It starts with a bit, say (without loss of generality) a zero bit.  Now, you generate additional random bits and stop when you get a one.  There is a $p$ probability that the very next bit is a $1$, so your second collection has size $1$.  There is a $(1-p)p$ probability that you get one more zero, and then a $1$, in which case your second collection has size $2$.  Can you continue?